# Cannot login to some sites due to auto-login failing

Tags: support, login, authentication

Autologin prevents me from logging into some SE sites.
Here is what is happening:

1. visit https://superuser.com/; the top line says `Stack Exchange ... sign up  ... log in` (i.e., I am *not* logged in despite being logged in to meta, SO and a few others)
2. click on either `sign in` or `log in`: I am taken to the `login` page where I can select between Google, SE &c
3. Immediately (within 1 sec) the "welcome back" banner appears
4. Immediately (within 1 sec) I am taken back to https://superuser.com/ - but I am *not* logged in (the top line is the same as before, I cannot ask and answer questions).
5. neither reloading, nor clicking on `login with Google` before the "welcome back" banner appears helps - I just cannot login.

Additionally, the same is happening on, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/, https://superuser.com/, https://mathoverflow.net/, https://serverfault.com/ now - however, I did manage to create a new account on another SE site (so, I guess, there is no limit on the number of SE sites I can be logged into simultaneously).

- I am using Firefox 25 (just updated to 26 - same behavior) on MacOSX 10.9.1; reproduced with add-ons disabled
- I use a Google account to log in to SE.

With Safari 7.0.1 and Chrome 31, I have to *manually* click on `log in` and then on `log in with Google`, but, so far, I never failed to get logged on - *yet*. I.e., auto-login does *not* work, but at least I can login manually.

Comment: no repro for me on FF26 on windows 7

Comment: @rene: how many SE accounts are you logged into ATM?

Comment: Only google? hold on

Comment: You are using a stackexchnage account? or another OpenId provider?

Comment: @rene: I login with a google acct

Comment: Well, I tried a couple of things but I can't repro your scenario with my google account on win7. Does FF on a mac comes with the 'restart without addons' option in 'Help' menu? Can you give that a try?

Comment: @rene: yes, I restarted without the addons and I observe the exact same behavior.

Comment: Can you use safari or Chrome to see if it repro's there as well?

Comment: @rene: safari & chrome are the same: autologin does not work, but login does

Comment: I'm out of options. You'll have to wait for a dev to pick this up.

Comment: I'm betting that your cookies are somehow corrupted. Has you tried on a clean slate browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Preferences` --> `Privacy` --> `remove individual cookies` --> remove the cookies for the broken sites --> everything works!